# Filter sequences

Tags: python, biopython

I have a bit of a fight with biopython, I am trying to filter a set of protein sequences based on 3 criterias:
1) The sequence contains a start codon, represented as M in my protein.fasta file
2) The sequence contains a stop codon, represented as *
3) The length between M and * is at least 90% of the length I expect, which is a new file

Here is what I tried to do, the conditions of the definitions are just a mess in my head and a bit of help would be really appreciated!

```
from Bio import SeqIO

source = 'protein.fasta'
outfile = 'filtered.fa'
sub1 ='M'
sub2 = '*'
length = 'protein_length.txt'

def seq_check(seq, sub1, sub2):
# basically a function to check whether seq contains both M and *, and is of the expected length

return

seqs = SeqIO.parse(source, 'fasta')
filtered = (seq for seq in seqs if seq_check(seq.seq, sub1, sub2, length))
SeqIO.write(filtered, outfile, 'fasta')


Protein datafile:
>comp12_c0_seq1:217-297
SR*THDYAALLTSHRSLDLVYVYNVV
>comp15_c0_seq1:3-197
*LCI*SCIVRVWLRYPSP*LANYFPQM*RLSAIRLF*ERLIYGPFLC*NYF*S*PKIAVHTYRS

Length datafile:
comp12_c0_seq1   50
comp15_c0_seq1   80
```

Thanks for your help
Claire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure that the proteins and lengths file are in the same order, you might want to modify the code not to use a dict to be more memory efficient for large data sets, e.g. write a generator function that yields the second column converted to int and then itertools.izip() it with SeqIO.parse().

```
def read_lengths(path):
    """Reads "length file" into dict mapping sequence ID to length."""
    lengths = {}
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            seq, length = line.strip().split()
            lengths[seq] = int(length)
    return lengths


def enclosed_substrings(s, start, stop):
    """Find all substrings starting with `start` and ending with `stop`."""
    startpos = 0
    stoppos = 0
    while True:
        startpos = s.find(start, startpos)
        if startpos < 0:
            break
        stoppos = s.find(stop, startpos + 1)
        if stoppos < 0:
            break
        yield s[startpos:stoppos + 1]
        startpos += 1


def seq_check(record, expected_lens, len_factor=0.9, start='M', stop='*'):
    min_len = expected_lens[record.id] * len_factor
    for sub in enclosed_substrings(record.seq, start, stop):
        if len(sub) >= min_len:
            return True
    return False


source_file = 'protein.fasta'
out_file = 'filtered.fa'
length_file = 'protein_length.txt'

expected_lengths = read_lengths(length_file)
seqs = SeqIO.parse(source_file, 'fasta')
filtered = (seq for seq in seqs if seq_check(seq, expected_lengths))
SeqIO.write(filtered, out_file, 'fasta')
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I wanted, I did not realise it was that complicated. Thanks for taking time to help me out

Comment: I don't think it is complicated. You can also replace `enclosed_substrings` by `re.findall()` if you want to. But then, http://xkcd.com/1171/